# jQuery wrappers for HTML fragment vs xmlDOM fragment?

Tags: jquery, xml, wrapper, xmldom

I don't understand the conceptual and functional difference between a jQuery wrapper around xmlDom object vs plain old html markup.

I can call jQuery methods on both but they act differently which surprises me a bit..  I guess I assumed I could wrap any html/ xml markup with jQuery and it would act about the same.

I'm using the xmlDOM plugin to get a jQuery wrapped xmlDom object:

http://outwestmedia.com/jquery-plugins/xmldom/

here's a fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/YL8bY/

```
<body>

<b>xmlDOM Wrapper</b>  <br />

XML fragment:  <br />
<div id="xmldomdiv1"></div>

HTML fragment:  <br />
<div id="xmldomdiv2"></div>


<b>jQuery Wrapper </b>  <br />

XML fragment:  <br />
<div id="jqdiv1"></div>

HTML fragment:  <br />
<div id="jqdiv2"></div>

</body>

<script>

var xmlfragment = '<book><title>My Book Title</title><author>Joe Author</author></book>';
var htmlfragment = '<div><p>My Book Title</p><p>Joe Author</p></div>';

var $xmldomxml = $.xmlDOM( xmlfragment );
var $xmldomhtml = $.xmlDOM( htmlfragment );

var $jqxml = $( xmlfragment );
var $jqhtml = $( htmlfragment );

$('#xmldomdiv1').append( $xmldomxml.find('title, author'));
$('#xmldomdiv2').append( $xmldomhtml.find('p'));

$('#jqdiv1').append( $jqxml.find('title, author'));
$('#jqdiv2').append( $jqhtml.find('p'));

console.log("Here's fragment vars:  ");
console.log($xmldomxml);
console.log($xmldomhtml);
console.log($jqxml);
console.log($jqhtml);

</script>
```

Comment: When you wrap XML in a jQuery object using `$()`, what you are really doing is creating an html dom fragment, not an XML document. How is jQuery supposed to know if "<section></section>" is HTML or XML? If you want XML, use `$.parseXML(xmlstring)` and if you want html, use `$.parseHTML()` for best results across all browsers (jQuery 1.8)

Comment: That's interesting. If you inspect the output markup, the jQuery wrapper outputs the same thing as the xmlDom wrapper. But, for some reason, the second xml `<title>...` is not displayed visually.

Comment: yes.. there are a number of subtle differences that led me to believe I don't really understand dom objects of any sort !  :)